# typing express & nestjs, start project errors

Tags: typescript, express, node-modules, nestjs, typescript-typings

I’m using nestJS. When I start the project, I have the following error. Is it a problem from the @types/express package ? Or is it something I did wrong ?
Thanks.

```
[14:17:06] Starting compilation in watch mode...

node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:99:42 - error TS2344: Type 'P' does not satisfy the constraint 'Params'.
      Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsArray'.

     extends core.ErrorRequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
                                        ~

node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:108:124 - error TS2344: Type 'P' does not satisfy the constraint 'Params'.
      Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsArray'.

     interface Request<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
                                                                                                                          
node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:109:138 - error TS2344: Type 'P' does not satisfy the constraint 'Params'.
      Type 'P' is not assignable to type 'ParamsArray'.

     interface RequestHandler<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
                                                                                                                                        
[14:17:17] Found 3 errors. Watching for file changes.
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` file?

Comment: fyi: an issue was raised in the GH repo regarding that https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/47339

Comment: @davidlj95 Thanks. I’ve looked for an opened issue, but It wasn’t opened yet. And I didn’t do it myself, I was afraid it was just me and my project.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with compilation, though just deleting `package-lock.json` didn't work for me. However, this did: `npm update @types/express-serve-static-core --depth 1`... It's suggested in the [linked issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/47339)

Comment: Wasn't even using this package, added and fixed my issue

Answer (score 3):

as mentioned [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/47339#issuecomment-689695381), just remove the package-lock.json, and reinstall packages.